# ImageMagick - Merge files with partial filename matches

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file, imagemagick, pdftk

these are my filenames in the folder

```
1710190363_1.jpg
1710190363_2.jpg
1711140603_1.jpg
1711140603_2.jpg
1711140603_3.jpg
1711140603_4.jpg
1711140603_5.jpg
```

All are .jpg files. File names are dynamic but unique count, first 10 digits then underscore following by a single digit.

Using imagemagick, I m trying to convert all the image files into pdf based on their first ten digits. I want the output as follows

```
1710190363.pdf
1711140603.pdf
```

Manually I got this run -

```
convert 1710190363_1.JPG 1710190363_2.JPG 1710190363.pdf
```

but dont know how to run in a loop

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do convert %a o_%a.pdf
```

Could anyone help me on this script.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What's wrong with `convert *.jpg result.pdf`?

Comment: If your files are JPEG images, why don't their names end in `.jpg`?

Comment: How can your question be tagged both `bash` and `powershell`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell He put `Bash`, `Batch`, And `powershell` as he is open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution, which assumes that:

- the numbers behind the `_` always start counting at `1`;
- the processing order of the equally prefixed files does not matter;

So here is the code to be used within a batch script:

```cmd
for /F "delims=_" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_1.jpg"') do convert "%%F_*.jpg" "%%F.pdf"
```

And here is the code to be used directly in command prompt (`cmd`):

```cmd
for /F "delims=_" %F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_1.jpg"') do @convert "%F_*.jpg" "%F.pdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using bash

Consider:

```
for f in *_1.jpg; do convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"; done
```

Or, for those who prefer commands spread over several lines:

```
for f in *_1.jpg
do
    convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"
done
```

**The above assumes that the jpeg file names end in `.jpg`.  If your jpeg file names actually end in `.JPG`, then use:**

```
for f in *_1.JPG; do convert "${f%_1.JPG}"*.JPG "${f%_1.JPG}.pdf"; done
```

#### Example

If we had a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
1710190363_1.jpg  1710190363_2.jpg  1711140603_1.jpg  1711140603_2.jpg  1711140603_3.jpg  1711140603_4.jpg  1711140603_5.jpg
```

And our command is:

```
for f in *_1.jpg; do convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"; done
```

Our command would cause `convert` to be executed twice as follows:

```
convert 1710190363_1.jpg 1710190363_2.jpg 1710190363.pdf
convert 1711140603_1.jpg 1711140603_2.jpg 1711140603_3.jpg 1711140603_4.jpg 1711140603_5.jpg 1711140603.pdf
```

#### How it works

- `for f in *_1.jpg; do`

  This starts a loop over variable `f` where `f` is the name of each file in the directory that ends with `_1.jpg`.
- `convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"`

  This runs `convert` for each group of files.

  `${f%_1.jpg}` is the name of the file with the trailing `_1.jpg` removed.  Consequently, the glob `"${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg` expands to a list of all names with the same starting prefix and ending with `.jpg`.  Similarly, `"${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"` is the name of the output file.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

Comment: thanks, I pasted the lines for f in *_1.jpg; do convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"; done but nothing happened, I have given pause at the stop but the command prompt is not stopped

Comment: First, the naming convention for your files was unclear to me.  Do you have a file named `1710190363_1.jpg` or just `1710190363_1` or `1710190363_1.JPG`?  Your exact convention is important.  Second, this may be a problem with SO formating but `f in _1.jpg ....` (as shown in the comment) won't work.  It needs to be `f in *_1.jpg ....`.  The `*` is important.  Let me know and then we address the next steps to take.

Comment: I think OP's filenames end in `.JPG` (uppercase) despite what he says. Have my vote anyway!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks!  Following up on your thought, I just added the JPG code to the answer.

Comment: this is  the line in my script = for f in (*_1.jpg) do (convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"; done

Comment: @Shenbagavalli Very good but `for f in (_1.jpg) do ...` is not it.  It needs the `*` added and the parens removed.  It should be `for f in *_1.jpg; do ...`.

Comment: I bet the `*` was actually there, but not in backticks, hence the italics in that comment.

Comment: yes, I have mentioned * but its not displayed here, its *_1.jpg only

Comment: @Shenbagavalli Very good.  In that case, we just need to remove the parens and add the semicolon between `jpg` and `do`.  (The curly braces remain unchanged.)

Comment: for f in *_1.JPG; do convert "${f%_1.JPG}"*.JPG "${f%_1.JPG}.pdf"; done

Comment: again * hided here but present in my script. Placed those seven jpg files and this script in a same folder. tried with .jpg as well as .JPG, no results, dont know what I missed out. One error shown in command prompt but unable to see that, even I given pause but it wont displayed

Comment: thanks John1024 for your explanations, finally aschipfl answer is working but I would like to know whats my mistake in the above line, is it % symbol or any

Comment: @Shenbagavalli Thanks for trying again.  To help see what is going wrong, first try `ls *_1.jpg` and let me know if you see the files correctly.  Second, try `for f in *_1.jpg; do echo convert "${f%_1.jpg}"*.jpg "${f%_1.jpg}.pdf"; done`.  This will show you what the `convert` commands look like.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group files by the first 10 digits resp. 1st elemtent split by the underscore.

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | 
    Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[0]} |
       ForEach-Object{
           &magick convert $($_.Group -join ' ') $_.Name+".pdf"
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Batch Solution**

In this response I will give a pure batch solution. Based off the fact you want to convert files based on the first 10 numbers in the name that are the same, we can extract all the file names, grab only the first 10 numbers, then add the names that match in a single string.

This process is a little complicated but I have put multiple `Rem` statements (Comments) for each process in the script to explain what it's doing.

**ConvertFilesBasedOnFileMatched.bat:**

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Count=1
set GetFName=1

Rem | Configuration
Set "MainDir=C:\New folder"
Set "Extension=.jpg"

Rem | Check If .XXX Files Exist
if not exist "!MainDir!\*!Extension!" (goto :EOF)

Rem | Grab All File Names
for %%A in ("!MainDir!\*!Extension!") do (

    Rem | Set as String, Grab First 10 Chars
    Set "CurrentName=%%~nA"
    Set "CurrentName=!CurrentName:~0,10!"

    Rem | Get First Name 
    If "!GetFName!"=="1" (

        Set "GetFName=2"

        Rem | Set as String, Grab First 10 Chars
        Set "FirstName=%%~nA"
        Set "FirstName=!FirstName:~0,10!"

    )

    Rem | Check For Differences
    If "!CurrentName!"=="!FirstName!" (

        set "CurrentList=!CurrentList! !CurrentName!_!Count!%%~xA"
        set /a "Count=!Count!+1"

    ) ELSE (

        Rem | Results Complete
        Convert !CurrentList:~1! !CurrentName!.pdf

        Rem | Reset For Future Loops
        set "Count=1"
        set "GetFName=1"
        set "CurrentList="

        Rem | Set Any Pending Data
        set "CurrentList=!CurrentList! !CurrentName!_!Count!%%~xA"
        set /a "Count=!Count!+1"

    )

)

Rem | Results Complete
Convert !CurrentList:~1! !CurrentName!.pdf

goto :EOF
```

---

Furthermore, If you need to address the path for each image tweak the following.

**Change both iterations of:**

```
set "CurrentList=!CurrentList! !CurrentName!_!Count!%%~xA"
```

**To**

```
set "CurrentList=!CurrentList! !MainDir!\!CurrentName!_!Count!%%~xA"
```

---

For any more help on the commands, type the following into a command prompt:

- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- Exc.